# in how many ways 5 projects be completed?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Working on data science project in which I need to find out in how many orders can five projects are completed such that
these include any three A projects and any two B software projects,
assuming that these projects are completed in a sequence (not
concurrently) Two orders are different if they have the same projects in a different order or have different projects.

I have got the answer for the 1st (5C3 * 4C2) part but I'm don't know how to solve 2nd part (about the sequence)

Comment: Why do you have ${2\choose 3}$ (2C3), and what two parts are you referring to? I am afraid that is not very clear. (Maybe you inadvertently omitted some information?)

Comment: sorry its 20C3 I forget 0 at the end

Comment: OK, so it seems that you have 20 total projects of type A and 4 or type B. You need to add that information to the question.

Comment: Again I'm sorry I have 5 Type A and 4 Type B projects

Comment: Also, please see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Your question appears to lack appropriate context (is it homework?, any background?, what did you try to solve it?). It will pro be downvoted and closed if you do not  edit it to include that.

Comment: no its not a homework working on data science project. Its just a small part of the bigger problem.

Comment: In that case, please edit the question to include the relevant information and how you got to 20C3. 4C2. Also, try to include the background(we call it context here). That we can see where you went wrong and give an answer better suited to your skull and experience level.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already determined, the number of ways of choosing the projects are ${5\choose 3}\cdot {4\choose 2}$.

Now, you can do them in any order, so you have to find the number of ways of arranging 5 objects, which is $5!$.

Thus, the answer is ${5\choose 3}\cdot {4\choose 2}\cdot (5!)$.